# Is it possible to get specific rows from a SQLite db with a specific value, convert it to JSON, and push to the webpage using Flask?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to grab specific rows from a SQLite document using Flask-SQLAlchemy, then to pipe it into JSON to it can be pushed to the page.
I'm semi-new to Flask and Python but I have enough knowledge to do what I need to make, I just can't figure out how.

My current code:

```
@app.route('/posts/<pid>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def posts(pid):
    if request.method == "POST":
        post = Posts.query.filter_by(id=pid).first()
        comment = request.form.get('comment')
        # poid = request.form.get('postid')
        poid = pid
        print(poid)
        c = Comments(id=len(Comments.query.all())+1, comment=comment, user=current_user.username, postid=poid)
        db.session.add(c)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("post.html", title=post.title, body=post.body, user=post.user, id=poid)
    post = Posts.query.filter_by(id=pid).first()
    # c = Comments()
    # print(json.dumps(c, cls=AlchemyEncoder))

    comments = Comments.query.filter_by(id=pid).all()
    jsonToPush = {'comments': []}
    print(comments)
    for comment in comments:
        print(comment.postid)
        if comment.postid == pid:
            print("Found comment")
            jsonToPush['comments'].append({ "id": comment.id, "postid": comment.postid, "comment": comment.comment, "user": comment.user})
            print(jsonToPush)
            return render_template("post.html", title=post.title, body=post.body, user=post.user, id=pid, jtp=jsonToPush)
    return render_template("post.html", title=post.title, body=post.body, user=post.user, id=pid)
```

When I `print(comments)` it prints out `[<Comments 1>]`

When I `print(comment.postid)` it prints out `1`

No matter how many comments there are, it only prints out `1`.

I already have plans on how I will utilize the JSON in the site, I just need help getting the SQL to the site. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

My current code is now this:

```
@app.route('/posts/<postid>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def posts(postid):
    post = Posts.query.filter_by(id=postid).first()
    if request.method == "POST":
        comment = request.form.get('comment')
        c = Comments(id=len(Comments.query.all())+1, comment=comment, user=current_user.username, postid=postid)
        db.session.add(c)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/posts/{}'.format(postid))
    # c = Comments()
    # print(json.dumps(c, cls=AlchemyEncoder))

    comments = Comments.query.filter_by(postid=postid).all()
    print(Comments.query.all())
    return render_template("post.html", title=post.title, body=post.body, user=post.user, id=postid, comments = [comment_dict(comment) for comment in comments])
```

Edit: I based this answer off of Attack68's answer below. Give him the kudos, not me :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually `id` in a database table is a `primary key` meaning it is `unique` and `not null`. The uniqueness is the key (no pun) here since when you execute this line `comments = Comments.query.filter_by(id=pid).all()` you will only acquire one comment by primary key constraint.

Note, secondly, there is a filter in jijna2 so that you can pass python objects to jinja2 without JSON formatting and it can be converted directly in the html for example:

```
render_template('some.html', arr=[1,2,3], dict={'pigs': 'nice', 'fish': 'unfriendly'})
===============
<div> {{ arr | tojson }} {{ dict | tojson }} </div>
```

Incidentally, note you can put this line: `post = Posts.query.filter_by(id=pid).first()` at the top of the function to avoid it being called twice in some cases. Actually thats not true it will only ever be called once but it looks nicer in my opinion only typed once! :)

Edit..

I'm assuming `Comments` is a table. Say you have a database model that looks like this (i'm just guessing):

```
def Comments(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'), nullable=False)
    data = db.Column(db.String)
```

Then you can create a dict generator for a `Comment` class. There are many places you could do this but here it is explicit function.

```
def comment_dict(comment):
    return dict(id=comment.id, post_id=comment.post_id, data=comment.data)
```

Then you can make a database query to return an iterator of comments and use list comprehension to form a list of dicts:

```
comments = Comments.query.all() # or some filtered subset
render_template(comments = [comment_dict(comment) for comment in comments])
```

In your html you can access comments as a JSON array of JSON objects with:

```
{{ comments | tojson }}
```

Comment: So would I be able to just do ```return render_template("post.html", title=post.title, body=post.body, user=post.user, id=pid, jtp=Comments())``` then in the HTML file just use ```{{ jtp | tojson}}```?

Comment: did the edit make it any clearer? If you do `jtp=Comments()` all you are doing is instantiating a new Comments object, you still need to query the database but the above code can arrange and order the returned DB results and jinja2 can parse to JSON.

Comment: Yes it did. I’ll try it later. Thanks!

Comment: That worked, however, it only took the first comment from the SQLite file.

Comment: put a debug line to see what `Comments.query.all()` returns. By definition it is supposed to return all comments, so if it returning just one then there can only be one. I use the other code in my projects so I am confident it works.

Comment: I did that, it printed `[]`.

Comment: Then you don't have any comments in your database. That is a fundamental database query equivalent to SQL statements `SELECT * FROM comments`, so if it returns an empty array the problem is likely with inserting elements into your database and not reading them. But in any case it looks like you have fixed it by using the code I supplied and then posting it as your own answer and accepting it. Hooray